# Lighting groups in Alexa

Tags: smart-home, alexa

I have paired several lights with Alexa (using an echo dot and the android app). All the lights work individually, and as groups "*turn off the lounge lights*".

On the app, I see the (sonoff) kitchen light with a dedicated button, but not the lights in the lounge (lightwaverf switches). As far as I can tell, the devices are all set to 'light', and they appear in the 'light' collection for the group, just without the elevated control button. Is this expected (only single light can be highlighted), or have I set up something wrong?

[image: Groups]
[image: kitchen]
[image: Lounge]
[image: Light]